# DBpedia SPARQL Query with Unicode

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

The following resource has an Unicode character in the name:
http://dbpedia.org/page/Marit_Bj%C3%B8rgen

The following query works for resource names without Unicode character but using name above it returns nothing:

```
select ?label { 
 dbpedia:Marit_Bjørgen
   dbpedia-owl:birthPlace
     [ a dbpedia-owl:Country ;
      rdfs:label ?label ]
  filter langMatches(lang(?label),"en")
 }
```

I have also tried various escaping:

```
dbpedia:Marit_Bj%C3%B8rgen
```

But this returns error. Anyone that knows how to do this?

Comment: What kind of error is returned when you escape the characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that a QName like `dbpedia:whatever` is just an abbreviation for a complete URI. This works:

```
select ?label { 
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Marit_Bj%C3%B8rgen>
    dbpedia-owl:birthPlace
      [ a dbpedia-owl:Country ;
        rdfs:label ?label ]
  filter langMatches(lang(?label),"en")
}
```

Comment: dbpedia:Marit_Bj%C3%B8rgen is legal SPARQL 1.1 for the URI.  It is a dofferent URI to dbpedia:Marit_Bjørgen -- it's not "escaping" - it's "encoding".  The URI really does have %-C-3-%-B-8 in it.

Comment: @AndyS But it’s [illegal SPARQL 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-query/#rPrefixedName), and e.g. [DBpedia’s own endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql) rejects it.

Comment: However, when I run this instead `prefix dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
ask {<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Marit_Bj%C3%B8rgen> a dbo:Person}` it does not seem to work correctly